# use an axios returned data in pug

Tags: javascript, html, object, axios, pug

What I am trying to do here, is to make an object that was returned from axios (front-end) known in the pug template so I can use it in multiple places. But I don't want to create the markeup and inject the data (because it will take me long) is this dowable? thank you in advance

The axios function below returns the carSearch, which is an object, and it is the same object I want to use in the pug template for example make it as global object inside the pug template.

```js
const btnSearchBodyType = document.querySelectorAll('.car-type');
let carBody = {};
btnSearchBodyType.forEach((el) =>
    el.addEventListener('click', async function() {
        carBody['body style'] = el.className.split(' ')[1];
        console.log(carBody);
        const carSearch = await searchBodyType(
            carBody, ['body style'],
            el.className.split(' ')[1]
        );
        console.log(carSearch);
    })
);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  The pug template is processed server-side, the page is sent to the client, that page then makes an AJAX request to get data... How is that data then related to the original pug template?  Are you trying to use that data on another page after the user leaves this page?  Something else?  Please elaborate.

Comment: In other words, I want to render the object to the pug so I could use it right inside of pug to extract data when and where I need it

Comment: So you want to do this on the server, before delivering the page to the client?  If that's the case then you'd have to make this AJAX request on the server, before delivering the page to the client.  Then you'd supply the object to the template when rendering the template and returning the page to the client.

Comment: thank you for the reply @David. so I have the backend and the frontend for this. I pass the object in the backend when the page is first rendered and everything looks good. but the client is filtering data on the page (car search) and I depend on DOM elements to extract these filters. so when the cliens selects a filter, I use that to get the data using ajax call but right in the frontend using the function above, I get the data back and everything, but instead of creating markup and inject the data, I want that data to be known in the pug twmplate just like I would from the backend server.

Comment: Then you probably would need to do one of two things.  Either (1) make a request back to the server to process the pug template and return the rendered HTML, or (2) see if you can use pug in the browser, in which case you'd fetch the template from the server and then process/compile the template with the data you have from the AJAX response, and update the DOM with the result of that process.  Overall what you're asking is pretty broad and you have different ways you can approach it depending on how your system is designed.  Your best bet is to pick the most appropriate and give it a try.

Comment: I am trying to follow the second approach, but I can't wrap my head around how to re-render the pug template with the new data from the frontend, i will include more code to illustrate this once I am in front of my pc again